# Logic may break somewhere in jquery discoun

Tags: jquery

This is the example - but the problem is that it stops at the product which does not have sale price, say "I Love London Mini Frame Purse" for $135. It will continue to find class item but will stop at the product which has only one actual price (no sale price). Why is that? Can't it continue finding class item and calculate accordingly till the end of the page ignoring the products with actual price only?

```
function calculate(sale, original) {

    percentDiscount = Math.round(eval((sale / original) * 100));

    return percentDiscount;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var salecost;
    var originalcost;
    var percent;
    $('.item').each(function() {
        salecost = $(this).find('.saleprice').html();
        salecost = salecost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");


        originalcost = $(this).find('.actualprice').html();
        originalcost = originalcost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
        percentDiscount = calculate(salecost, originalcost);
        if (percentDiscount > 30) {

            $(this).find("#percentoff").html((percentDiscount) + '%');
            $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge30');
        }

        if (percentDiscount > 50) {

            $(this).find("#percentoff").html((percentDiscount) + '%');
            $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge50');
        }

        if (percentDiscount > 70) {

            $(this).find("#percentoff").html((percentDiscount) + '%');
            $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge70');
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**
One question
if 0 and 30 = green color
if 30 and 50 = brown color
if 50 and 70 = yellow color
if 70 and 100 = red color

would it be this:

```
 if (50> percentDiscount > 70) {

                    $(this).find("#percentoff").html((percentDiscount) + '%');
                    $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge70');
                }
```

**EDIT II**
ANother question:

how to have price in html to be appended to div percentoff?

```
$(this).find("#percentoff").append.html((percentDiscount) + '%');
```

Comment: @just a comment why do you need eval for calculating sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange that it stops midway through the page, but perhaps you could just use an if statement?

i.e., change

```
salecost = $(this).find('.saleprice').html()
```

to

```
if (salecost = $(this).find('.saleprice').html()) {
```

(with a closing bracket, of course)

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for your help! it works. but why does if works while find doesn't?

Comment: @josephine thats kind of null check , if there is no results it won't execute the code.

Comment: @Josephine I think what's happening is that when .find returns nothing, salecost is undefined.  You pass salecost to calculate() and try to division with it, which is going to fail.

Comment: @Jeff, thanks and also i have a question -- see above.. i am not sure how it goes, because one time i tried that it doesn't go right as i wanted it to behave.

Comment: @Jospehine I don't think you can have multiple operators in an if statement like that..  I think you mean to do something like if ((percentDiscount >= 50) && (percentDiscount < 70))

Comment: @jeff, I see it is troublesome.. hmm. I think it is not necessary to do background color for different %. thanks for your help :)